# How to force a tombstone/crash in a Froyo phone?

Tags: android, tombstoning

How to force a tombstone/crash in a Froyo phone?

I need a way to perform a test, forcing a tombstone generation in a Froyo phone. Preferably using adb commands.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to figure out how to do it from java code, but it's easy from native code, and you wanted to trigger it from adb anyway.

Compile the following as a stand alone native executable and launch it from the adb shell:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int *p=0;
  *p=1;    //will seg fault
  return 0;
}
```

You could probably also do this as a native subroutine to a normal android application and launch that from adb with the am start command